# Python list check if 2 largest values are the same

Tags: python, list, function, max

In python, is it possible to check if the 2 largest values in a list are the same?

This is my code:

```
list=[[A, teamAScore], [B, teamBScore], [C, teamCScore], [D, teamDScore]]
list.sort()
print(max(list))
```

If the largest 2 values are the same, the max function will only return one of them. Is there a way to check if the two last values in the list are the same, so I can compare them in a different way? (Separate function etc etc)

A, B, C and D are Strings. teamAScore etc. are integers

Comment: Can you be a bit less abstract, please? Which values are you comparing here? Are A, B etc strings and teamAScore etc ints?

Comment: Sorry, A, B, C and D are strings. teamAScore etc. are integers

Comment: So you want to see if maximum integer appears two time

Comment: Correct, and if it does appear twice, set a new variable to 1, or print something so that I know it has happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume  you want the max based on the score i.e the second element so first get the max based on the second element of each sublists  scores then keep all sublists that have a score equal to the max:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[A, teamAScore], [B, teamBScore], [C, teamCScore], [D,   teamDScore]]
# get max of list based on second element of each sublist i.e teamxScore
mx = max(lst,key=litemgetter(1)))

# use a list comp to find all sublists where teamxScore is equal to the max
maxes = [ele for ele in lst if ele[1] == mx[1]]
```

Demo:

```
l = [["foo", 2], ["bar", 1], ["foobar", 2]]
mx = max(l, key=itemgetter(1))

maxes = [ele for ele in l if ele[1] == mx[1]]
```

Output:

```
[['foo', 2], ['foobar', 2]]
```

Both foo and foobar had a score equal to the max so we get both sublists returned.

Comment: I don't understand any of that code xD, but I'll try and use it - thanks

Comment: Thank you for the added explaination - makes more sense. To actually print an output, what do I need to add?

Comment: @Humvee202, no worries, just print maxes

Comment: Thank you. I will incorportate this into my main code now :)

Comment: Sorry, one more question. If this comes up as true (As in, there are 2 values the same, how do I then set another variable to 1 to initiate another set of code? is it something like: if maxes == true?

Comment: `if len(maxes:) > 1`  would mean we have at least another match, do you actually want the matches or just to know if there are matches

Comment: I need to know which ones are the matches please. Also, thanks again for all the help

Comment: No prob, then the code will do what you want as is, just print the maxes list to see the matches or iterate over it to use them.

Comment: I actually figured out a way to do it without - but thanks anyway :D.  I should be good now